# DRY html using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a webpage where you can select a grid size. I want to do this by showing the client a large grid (say 10x10) and then have him select the size by clicking on a grid element (similar to how you select a table size in word). To do this, I obviously need a large grid and the elements have to have an id like 5, 6 to denote their position in the table.

Of course I could create this table by hand, that is write out all the html code by hand. That wouldn't take forever but it's not very dry. I have had the idea to use Javascript with loops to automatically create a string that is the html code for the table and then use jQuery to set the html property of some div to that string.

Would that be an elegant solution or would it be considered bad because I have to execute a client-side script before showing anything on the page? If it is not elegant, what would be an elegant solution?

Comment: you need js to use the table maker anyway, so don't worry about that part. using js to make an empty table is a fine use, and prefereable to shipping a lot of empty markup only some users need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy enough with a couple of `for` loops:

```
var table = document.createElement('table'),
    tbody = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody')),
    tr, td, x, y;
for( y=0; y<10; y++) {
    tr = tbody.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
    for( x=0; x<10; x++) {
        td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    }
}
tbody.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var t = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while( t != this && t.nodeName != "TD") t = t.parentNode;
    if( t != this) {
        alert("You clicked on cell "+t.cellIndex+" in row "+t.parentNode.rowIndex+"!");
    }
};
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

This is a perfectly valid use of JavaScript, since you'll be using JS to handle clicks anyway (probably!) and it makes things a lot easier.

EDIT: If the brief delay isn't acceptable, you may want to consider using a server-side language like PHP:

```
<?php
echo "<table><tbody>";
for( $y=0; $y<10; $y++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for( $x=0; $x<10; $x++) {
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

This will be visible as soon as the page loads.

Comment: +1 really nice answer. I just have one thing to contribute, maybe he can use JQUERY to properly handle incompatibility issues.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico There are no incompatibility issues here. I have covered them all in [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Comment: Yes, so it will be simple to use jquery and avoid the code to cover them :)

Comment: @gustavodidomenico Sure, if you like bloating your codebase for no reason.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm a beginner with web development so I don't really understand how your code interplays with the html. I get the loop part to create the table. But is this just an ordinary html table? And how is it included in the html document.

Comment: Yup, it's a plain old table. `document.body.appendChild` puts it in your document, but you could use a placeholder `<div id="tableGoesHere"></div>` and do `document.getElementById('tableGoesHere').appendChild(table);` instead.

Comment: Thank you, that helps me. I don't get the clicking part though (the tutorials I followed never used plain js, but always jQuery). Can you maybe give a short explanation of that, too?

Comment: It works in three steps: First, get the element you clicked on. This will be `t`. Second, go up `parentNode`s until you either find a `<td>`, or get to `this` (the tbody in this case, since it's the element the event is attached to). If it's not `this` then we found a table cell, so gets its `cellIndex` and the row's `rowIndex` and alert them.

Comment: Allright, now I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just as an extra, the check for `this` is to make sure we stop checking once you "fall out" of the table.